# Running a method on UI thread

Tags: android, android-runonuithread

My question seems very simple but i can't seem to the logic right. 
Am trying to run methods from other classes using the UI thread. I could do this this simply by wrapping my methods like this

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Log.d("UI thread", "I am the UI thread");
           ui.myMethod("changetext");
    }
});
```

but my goal is to have a class that wraps **methods** to be run on the UI thread as having `runOnUiThread()` almost 5 times in a single class seems very untidy. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're calling the same UI method repeatedly, you could streamline the client code by creating the `Runnable` in a method:

```
private void updateUi(final String message) {
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         ui.myMethod(message);
      }
   });
}
```

Then your client code would simply call `updateUi("changetext")`.  (This code assumes that `ui` is final.  If not, you could pass in a final reference.)

If you're calling a different UI method every time, this doesn't gain you anything as you'd need a separate update method for each UI method.  Your existing code is as elegant as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to do this from multiple classes, you could create a public static method that will run a runnable on the main thread. Something like this:

```
public class Util {
    public static void runOnUI(Activity a, Runnable r){
        a.runOnUIThread(r);
    }
}
```

You call it by doing something like this:

```
Util.runOnUI(getActivity(), mRunnable);
```

Comment: I don't see how this gains you anything.

Comment: You just don't have to rewrite runOnUIThread(new Runnable().....); over and over again. I just answered his question, didn't say it was the right thing to do.

Comment: Right... instead you rewrite something else over and over again, *plus* an additional parameter.

Comment: I've got nothing... Do you have something better in mind?

Comment: thanks, this helped me, I know it is tedious and unnecessary to rewrite the new Runnable()...etc if you make multiple calls to UIThread